# Rails send data to a serial on client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, printing, serial-port

I need to print from my rails app to a printer on the client side of my app

How can I acess the printer from browser to print on client side with rails?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers won’t let you do this without user interaction (the user will need to select print from the file menu while looking at your app’s page).

If you’re ok with that; then this isn’t so much a rails problem as creating a view which will print nicely. For that you’ll want to look at css for print media types.

But before we get any deeper - do you require that your web app have direct access to the printer without user interaction?